# how to train tensorflow object detection model avoid to detect people on televisons?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I use tensorflow object detection model to detect people on images,but  there are　alse some televisions on images, and there are people on television. the model will detect people on television, how can i train   the model to avoid to detect people on television, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of most television is to present a lifelike image. It's probably impossible to detect if the pixel represents a real image or a TV image.

What might work, depending a lot on your scenario, is to train a separate model to detect televisions. Once you detect it you can black-out the area detected and feed the new image to your original model. Alternatively, ignore the objects detected that overlap with the television. This will introduce false positives that will cause you to fail to detect certain objects in certain contexts.