# Checking if the camera is recording a laptop screen

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, android-camera

I have a Tensorflow object detection model on an Android phone. It works well when detecting a keyboard or a laptop.

The problem is when I keep the phone's camera close to a laptop's screen and the laptop runs a movie. My phone will start detecting objects in the movie, instead of detecting the fact that a laptop is displaying that movie.

Is there a way to detect if the Android camera is looking at an actual object and not a movie or registration of that object?

Answer (score 0):

Question is similar to this one responded by someone else which i remember seeing :), hope it helps

[how to train tensorflow object detection model avoid to detect people on televisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534790/how-to-train-tensorflow-object-detection-model-avoid-to-detect-people-on-televis)